# Can you raise trigonometric functions to a non-integer power?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I don't inmediately see any reason why you could not yet I have never come across it. For any answer given reasoning would also be appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: Sure (modulo the usual problem of what a negative number raised to a non-integer power should mean).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as mrf said there is no reason not to except for the problem with negative numbers